# Combining minimum number of days in a time interval

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I'm looking to only select values with columns x>0, y>0, z>0  if they are continuously like that for at least half the amount of time in a time interval to 2/3 of that time (interval being set by the user in a filter on a dashboard. So is from the current date to whenever they specify). The other proportion which could also be half the amount of time in the interval or 1/3 on the interval depending on the first condition, needs to have certain values as well like x= 0, y>0, z>0 for that period of time.

To re-iterate with example:

Condition 1: x>0, y>0, z>0 for minimum half the amount of time to max 2/3 in that time interval. ex. if range set by user is 14 days in filter, then needs to have those values continuously for minimum 7 days to a max of 9 days in those 14 days.

Condition 2: x= 0, y>0, z>0 for rest of remaining time which can be another half or 1/3 depending on how many days was in the first condition. ex. if range set by user is 14 days in filter, and condition 1 took up 8 days, then condition 2 has to have x=0, y>0, z>0 for 6 days continuously.

Comment: An example with data in a *text* tabular form would really help.  It is unclear what your data looks like, and also what results you want.

Comment: So the records you are selecting are time-based and by "continuous" you mean that every single record in chronological order has to have those values with the condition that it has to be 1/2 to 2/3 of the time range?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes continuous meaning every single day during that time frame, and 1/2 to 2/3 for the first condition and 1/3 to 1/2 for the second condition based on the first